# JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) does not working in java 6 but working fine in java 7+. what is the alternate way to work java 1.6

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

i have a problem in right click popup menu in JTable Header. I found the solution to use JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) but its not working in java 6. But its working fine in java 7+. I have tried the not static method too. 
Why it is not working in java 6? 
What is the another way to achieve the same in java 6.

**JDK version** - JDK1.6.0_45

**Windows** - Windows 7 , Service pack 1.

And I want to know in which java version they gave fix?

**Oracle Bug:**

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4172190

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4169858

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It’s hard to believe that you are a victim of a seventeen year old bug that affected Java 1.1.